# How do I hold a jms message in queue until it is saved?

Tags: jms, weblogic-10.x

I just started using Weblogic JMS. I was able to send messages to the queue and pull them off with a messagebean. Now I want to save the message to a database.

So my question is, how do I tell JMS not to delete the message from the queue until I have successfully written the message to the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to send messages to the queue and pull them off with a
>   messagebean.

I suppose you are talking about message-driven bean ([MDB](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipko.html))?

> So my question is, how do I tell JMS not to delete the message from
>   the queue until I have successfully written the message to the
>   database?

MDBs are part of implicit container-managed transaction and the message will not be removed as long as your transaction hasn't commited (that is, as long as your `onMessage` method hasn't reached its end).

In case of rollback (i.e. you throw an exception or call `context.setRollbackOnly()` on the `MessageDrivenContext`), message will be redelivered. You can avoid this behaviour by making transaction bean-managed or using `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)`, but in your situation that should not be the case. Stick with default configuration and everything should work as you wish.